# Do modern terminals generally render all utf-8 characters correctly?

Tags: c, linux, unicode, portability

I am writting an application in C that will be ran in a terminal, and it would be handy but not necesary to use some of the less used unicode characters. From my experimentation, I have not had any trouble rendering them. However, I would not use any non ascii characters if it were a likely source of trouble in the future.

So, in short, can I count on just about any terminal or terminal emulator in the modern *nix world (mainly linux, freebsd, and osx) to properly render arbitrary utf-8 characters?

If I cannot make such an assumption, there are particular subsets of unicode characters defined for various purposes, so would some such subset at least be reliably rendered in any likely modern *nix terminal or terminal emulator?

NOTE: When I say arbitrary, I do mean arbitrary: any unicode characters. But for completeness of my question, I will note that I am primarily interested in arrows and mathematical characters, this link has lists of both: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_symbols.

Comment: I don't believe many hardware terminals, even ones currently being made, will deal with UTF-8 correctly.

Comment: Are hardware terminals still a thing? I imagine that, if they exist, they're probably still computers running stripped-down Linux and a terminal emulator.

Comment: Besides, I'm pretty sure you'd have to use some encoding to get Unicode through RS-232.

Comment: @TrippKinetics You mean like UTF-8?

Comment: What type of terminal is this? The traditional serial port terminals are/were ASCII or EBCDIC. You'd have to look up the terminal specs to see what the  actual character set is.

Comment: @rcgldr That's precisely what I was talking about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you should not assume that. Even in a modern system, the set of fonts installed, the font used by the terminal application, and environment variables such as `LANG`, `LC_*`, etc. may influence whether certain characters can be displayed correctly on the terminal or not.

You might be able to make reasonable guesses based on the value of the `TERM`, `LANG`, and `LC_*` environment variable as to what is supported, but it's still going to be a guess. I'd suggest either not relying on it at all or providing some means of enabling/disabling the use (via an environment variable and/or via commandline flags to the application).

Comment: In addition, "drawing UTF8" is only half the story. The other half is whether you expect to draw complex scripts (Arabic, Hebrew) and/or combinations of characters (such as Apple's new "I can see you" icon) correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to find some cases where I would want my program to function where I have very little rendering options (the FreeBSD cli for example). I guess guessing and switches are the best I can do.

Comment: @Jongware UTF-8 is an encoding format for Unicode... assuming "any UTF8" was supported (though that's really the incorrect way to phrase it ... the real question is.. does the terminal support all Unicode code points and, if so, in what encoding format), that would presumably include Arabic/Hebrew and Emoji.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, this depends on the font, not the terminal. But there are a couple of things the terminal software has to take into account. For example, [halfwidth and fullwidth forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms) of CJK characters.

Also, Unicode characters are added on a regular basis. There's no way that every font and terminal software is automatically updated as soon as a new version of the Unicode standard is released.

In general, you should assume that there are always Unicode characters that are not rendered correctly, even on a modern terminal.