# Reasonably determine whether terminal can correctly render UTF-8 characters in C?

Tags: c, unicode, terminal, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm writing a program in C where I'd like to print specific Unicode characters, e.g., → ("rightwards arrow"), ∅ ("empty set"), etc., to the terminal in certain places, so I'd like to programmatically determine whether the terminal can render characters printed via their UTF-8 encodings correctly. If not, I would fall back to displaying ASCII equivalents, e.g., -> instead of →.

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32928661/99089) as a starting point, I've come up with:

```c
_Bool terminal_supports_utf8( void ) {
  setlocale( LC_CTYPE, "" );
  char const *const encoding = nl_langinfo( CODESET );
  return  strcasecmp( encoding, "utf8"  ) == 0 ||
          strcasecmp( encoding, "utf-8" ) == 0;
}
```

It *seems* to work fine. Thoughts?

**NOTE**: this is supposed to work for *most* cases in the modern world where people use virtual (software) terminals.  For outlier cases, I would also provide a way for the user to force UTF-8 support either on or off. But I'd like the default to "just work" *most* of the time.

**NOTE**: I'm aware this isn't perfect. (Perfect is the enemy of good.) If you can write a better function, please do.

Comment: Take the extreme case of a serial terminal connected to a Unix-like system.  How could the program possibly know if the terminal understands UTF-8?

Comment: @MarkRansom If the user has their locale set to UTF-8, then it's set incorrectly. That's on them. Hence the addition of the provision to force UTF-8 off.

Comment: Checking `TERM` environment variable may help. It is the way we tell programs about capabilities of terminal, but it is not a direct link: we can lie. Else is LC_CTYPE (as you use), but sometimes is about locale (or system) and not terminal capability. Or just assume UTF-8 and people will possible set terminal to the expected UTF-8

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I don't think `TERM` is relevant. On my system, `TERM` is `xterm-256color`. `LANG`, however, is `en_US.UTF-8` — and that's why my code uses `nl_langinfo()`.

Comment: Not all xterm versions will display UTF-8 (and it is really a terminal issue handling multibytes (like UTF-8) but using only one cell (or two in wide scripts).

Comment: You could "cheat" and make it a requirement to use a UTF8 capable device when using your program.

Comment: Just because the terminal supports UTF-8, it doesn't mean the *font* supports the glyph.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I'm aware of that which is why I said _most_ cases. Most != all.

Comment: @TedLyngmo If I wanted it to be a requirement, I wouldn't have asked my question at all.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Furthermore, if the user claims their terminal supports UTF-8 via their settings but then chooses a font that can't display all valid Unicode glyphs, that's on them.

Comment: Most fonts don't support all valid Unicode glyphs, and how would the user know what glyphs you wanted to use?

Comment: @MarkTolonen All used glyphs will be documented in the man page. I'm even planning on allowing the user to override the default glyphs used to anything they want.

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas _"If I wanted it to be a requirement..."_ - No, I get that, but your program would still be usable by 99.-something % of the people out there and it would simplify things a lot. You could still make your program as-if there was some way reliable way to detect utf8 support and mock the "false" case while testing the non-utf8 modes - until the day you find that your current workaround isn't good enough and need to dig deeper. Chances are that you will never have to do that.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I guess; but — so far — _nobody_ has yet said whether the C code I wrote above is the best that's possible or if there's some better way to detect UTF-8 support in _most_ cases.

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas Yeah, I get that too. It's too bad we've "inherited" the TTY eras unidirectional communication in certain situations. It will be nice, in the future, when just asking the device what capabilities it has is a non-issue.